# Passing urls to relational collections in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I'm using [Backbone relational](http://backbonerelational.org/) and it's great. The problem I have run into is when I need the backend to provide the url for models to attach to.

This isn't such a problem when using one-to-one relationships because the model can hold onto the url as an attribute of itself.

The collection on the other hand creates a separate model within itself.

What is the best way to bind these together. Examples below

```
{
    "user": {
        "url": "http://example.com/api/user/1"
    },
    "permissions": {
        "url": "http://example.com/api/user/1/permissions"
    }
}
```

In the above example, I want user to be a model with the url provided, and the permissions a collection, with the url provided.

What I have tried is to get the collection working is the following:

```
{
    "permissions": {
        "url": "https://example.com/api/user/1/permissions"
        "data": []
    }
}
```

But I wasn't able to run a parse that extracts the variables out.

Comment: More information would be helpful. I assume these definitions you're providing are from your Backbone model? What data does your server return from "https://example.com/api/user/1/permissions"?

Comment: Does url: accept a function that can return a customized url?

Comment: @Morslamina The data returned from /api/user/1/permissions is an array of  objects to be parsed as models, their details not important. The above JSON is provided to the server to be added to the models later. If anything is provided in the data array they are parsed as models, just as if the url had been fetched.

Comment: So does the collection as currently written correctly fire the request and get the data? If so, is your problem parsing that data? Or are you having trouble even getting the request to fire to the server?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "I need the backend to provide the url for models to attach to"? Do you mean that you need the server to have it's own URL? That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Morslamina The problem is parsing what the server sends and parsing it to a working collection. As in, what ever is in the data object, being parsed as models in the collection and the url being used as the collections url.

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using to fire the request?

Comment: Also your parse function?

Comment: I'll add more details tonight.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Did my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not set `{parse: true}` on your relation definition ([documentation](http://backbonerelational.org/#relations-parse)), then you should do so, and see if that fixes your problem. Otherwise, it would help if you provided more code.